# Routing area in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a profile site and now i want to make it easy to remember the url.

I have links like

- www.page.com/faq
- www.page.com/news/1
- www.page.com/rules
- www.page.com/profile/[USERNAME]

Now, i want to change the url, www.page.com/profile/[USERNAME] to be, www.page.com/[USERNAME]. The profile is a own area in my project.

My ProfileAreaRegistration.cs

```
    public override string AreaName => "Profile";

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Profile_media",
            "Profile/{ProfileName}/Media/{id}",
            new
            {
                area = "Profile",
                controller = "Media",
                action = "Index"
            },
            new[] { "MySite.Areas.Profile.Controllers" });

        context.MapRoute(
            "Profile_default",
            "Profile/{ProfileName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new
            {
                area = "Profile",
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            },
            new[] { "MySite.Areas.Profile.Controllers" });

    }
```

My RouteConfig.cs

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "News", // Route name
            "News/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new {controller = "News", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
            new[] {"MySite.Controllers.News"}
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
            new[] {"MySite.Controllers"}
            );
    }
```

How can i get www.page.com/rules and www.page.com/[USERNAME] working? When i enter www.page.com/[USERNAME], the area Profile should be called.

Comment: Since [USERNAME] can be any string value, you need to make sure the profile route is the last one being added to the routing table, to prevent hijacking all your prefedined routes. But still you need to wonder if you really want [USERNAME] to be a top level directory kind of route. What if someone has `faq` or `rules` as it's username? That can cause lot's of conflicts in your routes...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it can be problem if a username is faq or rules. I can allways protect faq and rules from the username when the user create the account or i can change the address, www.page.com/faq -> www.page.com/start/faq. But for now, where should i start to send www.page.com/[USERNAME] to area www.page.com/Profile/[USERNAME]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave out `Profile` from the ProfileArea route, like this:

```
public override string AreaName => "Profile";

public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Profile_media",
        "{ProfileName}/Media/{id}",
        new
        {
            area = "Profile",
            controller = "Media",
            action = "Index"
        },
        new[] { "MySite.Areas.Profile.Controllers" });

    context.MapRoute(
        "Profile_default",
        "{ProfileName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new
        {
            area = "Profile",
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        },
        new[] { "MySite.Areas.Profile.Controllers" });

}
```

Comment: When i remove Profile, all requests is routing to /Profile/[USERNAME] even /faq & /rules.

Comment: You need to make sure the area registration happens after your regular route registration. Can you verify this? What is the order of execution in RouteConfig?

Comment: Yes, now it works. I changed the order, removed the default route in RegisterRoutes and add all pages(faq, rukes...)